# Accept a-z and 0-9 (restrict a-z to be lowercase without accents like ñ or ó)

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery: While the user types, Im trying to find a way to restrict a field to only accept a-z and 0-9, restricting a-z be lowercase without accents like ñ or ó.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="signup_username" name="signup_username">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jose, this is not a WordPress question and would be better suited for Stack Overflow.  I vote to close and migrate it to the proper site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery is my favorite js library anything you can think of already has a plugin, in your case check out 
**jQuery AlphaNumeric**
 http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/